# PHPで配列をループで取り出す

Tags: php

下記の配列が`debug($val)`で取り出されます。ここの、`Productfiles`の`file`をループで取り出したいのですが、どのように記述すればいいですか？

```
<?php foreach ($products as $key => $val): ?>
   <?php debug($val); ?>           
<?php endforeach; ?>

array(
    'Product' => array(
        'id' => '1'
     ),

    'Productfiles' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'product_id' => '1',
            'file' => 'https://user.zip'
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'id' => '2',
            'product_id' => '1',
            'file' => 'https://controller.zip'
        )
    ),
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

配列構造を崩していいのか分からなかったのでそのまま作成
多重ループで回せばいいかと思います。
[テストリンク](http://viper-7.com/QKJ6V9)

```
<?php 
    foreach ($products as $val): 
        //ファイルパスのみ抽出(構造そのまま？)
        $f_paths = array();
        foreach ($val['Productfiles'] as $file): 
            $f_paths[] = array('file'=>$file['file']);
        endforeach;
        //'Productfiles'を上書き
        $val['Productfiles'] = $f_paths;
?>
        <?php debug($val); ?>
<?php 
    endforeach;
?>
```